# Apart from the USA, what other countries offer something similar to the Diversity Lottery Program?

Tags: us-citizens, citizenship, australian-citizens

I'm just curious. I want to know whether other countries offer anything similar to the U.S. diversity lottery program and, if so, where can I find information on these equivalent programs.

Answer (score 1):

While it is hard to prove a negative the DV lottery is a product of American politics that may be unique to the US and no where else.

What became the DV lottery started off as [an effort by Irish-American politicians to find a way to legalize the rather large Irish population living illegally in the US](https://www.pressreader.com/ireland/irish-independent/20170804/281779924210622) who hadn't been there long enough to benefit from the 1986 amnesty. When it was decided that a law to legalize the immigrants of one particular nationality was really inappropriate they instead came up with the DV lottery which was open to (almost) everyone but which Irish people (including those born in Northern Ireland, but excluding the rest of the UK) were far more likely to win than anyone else. While the problem this was meant to address has long since been solved the program continues to be law due, as far as I can tell,  to inertia (I really don't know if the Irish bias still persists).

That the DV lottery exists is hence due to the constraints of American laws and politics and the concerns of American politicians at the time it was established. I would be surprised if any other country decided that this was a sensible solution to any problem they were having, though I stand ready to be corrected.